# WSO2ESB- The 'name' attribute is required for a Proxy service definition

Tags: wso2, soa, rule-engine, complex-event-processing, wso2-esb

I have a problem in deploying this sample: "Complex Event Processing and Business Rule Management With SOA" (Link: http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/07/complex-event-processing-business-rule-management-soa)

I did all the details, but when I copy `"cepSample.xml"` file in the location `"wso2esb-4.6.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services"` I get this error in the console and I won't be deployed: 
`/WSO2/wso2esb-4.6.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services/cepSample.xml failed - Continue in fail-safe mode
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The 'name' attribute is required for a Proxy service definition`

Answer (score 0):

I try to create Proxy Service manually - and get this file (in ESB 4.8.1.)
May be it help you:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="cepSample"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="txAmount" expression="//reqFinancTx/amount/text()"/>
         <property name="financTx" expression="//reqFinancTx/financTx/text()"/>
         <dblookup>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <password>esb</password>
                  <user>esb</user>
                  <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brms_db</url>
                  <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>
             SELECT * FROM `BRMS_USER_INFO` where `user_id`=? </sql>
               <parameter expression="//reqFinancTx/userID" type="VARCHAR"/>
               <result name="balance" column="account_balance"/>
               <result name="userId" column="user_id"/>
               <result name="userName" column="name"/>
               <result name="access" column="accessability"/>
            </statement>
         </dblookup>
         <log>
            <property name="userId" expression="get-property('userId')"/>
            <property name="userName" expression="get-property('userName')"/>
            <property name="access" expression="get-property('access')"/>
            <property name="balance" expression="get-property('balance')"/>
            <property name="txAmount" expression="get-property('txAmount')"/>
            <property name="financTx" expression="get-property('financTx')"/>
         </log>
         <xslt key="sampleXSLT">
            <property name="accountBalance" expression="get-property('balance')"/>
         </xslt>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="STATE" value="PERSON_INFO_REQUEST"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/transactionValidatorService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="xxxxxx" expression="get-property('STATE')"/>
         </log>
         <switch source="get-property('STATE')">
            <case regex="PERSON_INFO_REQUEST">
               <log level="full"/>
               <property xmlns:brs="http://brs.carbon.wso2.org"
                         xmlns:ax26="http://transactionApprovalService.samples/xsd"
                         name="RESULT"
                         expression="//brs:processTransactionResponse/brs:TransactionResult/ax26:transactionCanProceed"/>
               <log>
                  <property name="RESULT" expression="get-property('RESULT')"/>
               </log>
               <switch source="get-property('RESULT')">
                  <case regex="true">
                     <clone>
                        <target>
                           <sequence>
                              <xslt key="cepXSLT">
                                 <property name="userId" expression="get-property('userId')"/>
                                 <property name="financTx" expression="get-property('financTx')"/>
                              </xslt>
                              <log level="full"/>
                              <send>
                                 <endpoint>
                                    <address uri="http://localhost:9766/services/localBrokerService/AllTransactions"/>
                                 </endpoint>
                              </send>
                           </sequence>
                        </target>
                        <target>
                           <sequence>
                              <dblookup>
                                 <connection>
                                    <pool>
                                       <password>esb</password>
                                       <user>esb</user>
                                       <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brms_db</url>
                                       <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                                    </pool>
                                 </connection>
                                 <statement>
                                    <sql> SELECT * FROM `BRMS_USER_INFO` where `user_id`=? </sql>
                                    <parameter expression="//reqFinancTx/userID" type="VARCHAR"/>
                                    <result name="balance" column="account_balance"/>
                                    <result name="userId" column="user_id"/>
                                    <result name="userName" column="name"/>
                                    <result name="access" column="accessability"/>
                                 </statement>
                              </dblookup>
                              <log>
                                 <property name="userId" expression="get-property('userId')"/>
                                 <property name="userName" expression="get-property('userName')"/>
                                 <property name="access" expression="get-property('access')"/>
                              </log>
                              <switch source="get-property('access')">
                                 <case regex="false">
                                    <xslt key="accLockedXSLT"/>
                                    <send/>
                                 </case>
                                 <case regex="true">
                                    <xslt key="txProceedXSLT"/>
                                    <send/>
                                 </case>
                              </switch>
                           </sequence>
                        </target>
                     </clone>
                  </case>
                  <case regex="false">
                     <log level="full">
                        <property name="sequence"
                                  value="outSequence - STATE 02 - response from CreditService"/>
                     </log>
                     <send/>
                  </case>
               </switch>
               <send>
                  <endpoint key="CreditEpr"/>
               </send>
            </case>
            <case regex="CREDIT_REQUEST">
               <log level="full">
                  <property name="sequence"
                            value="outSequence - STATE 02 - response from CreditService"/>
               </log>
               <send/>
            </case>
         </switch>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```